# Redirect to next port in Express server app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having a running server in localhost:3000, since it's already in use how can I redirect to the next port number when am running a different server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an error-handler to catch the `EADDRINUSE`-error.
To start listening, you could write something like this:

```
function startListening(port) {
  app
    .listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`))
    .on("error", (error) => {
      if (error.code === "EADDRINUSE" && port < 65535) {
        startListening(port + 1);
      } else {
        // Different error or no port avaliable
      }
    });

}

startListening(3000);
```

Then it would count up until it finds a ununsed port.
The problem is that whatever needs to serve your app (e.g. nginx reverse proxy) should know the new port. But this depends on your configuration / setup / what you want to do with that app.